# what does 255 limitation for integer in Mysql mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

As the question told, what if i want to have 256 numbers. Is this mean 256 as a number or byte? Because, i will definitely need more than 255

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 255 limit applys to a field with a type of byte, called a TinyInt in MySql. As the maximum value that can be represented in a single byte is 255.

An integer by default in MySql and most DBMS will be much larger than a single byte, in MySql it is 32bits, or 4 bytes long. This means it can store values from 0 to 4billion, or from -2billion to +2billion.

The official MySql reference for integer sizes is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Better to reference the actual MySQL documentation than 3rd party, especially when there could be differences between versions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Thanks OMG Ponies, good suggestion, I've added your link to my post

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-types.html
"255" is a limitation of unsigned tinyint.

Answer (score 0):

What 255 limit are you referring to?

This [page on MySQL numeric datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) clearly details the ranges available -- SMALLINT can hold between -32768 and 32767, INTEGER can hold a 32-bit signed integer value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to any INT/BIGINT/MEDIUMINT/SMALLINT/TINYINT has nothing to do with the limit on its size or its range of values.  It's just a hint for display width.

This is more useful if you use the ZEROFILL option for integer types.  So it pads the value with zeroes.  For example, storing 1234 into an INT(10) ZEROFILL column and fetching it back returns `"0000001234"`.  This makes some reporting look nicer.  But the value stored in the database is just 1234.

The display width number *doesn't* make a TINYINT store any more or any less than 8 bits, no matter how large you make the width.  Likewise SMALLINT is always 16 bits, MEDIUMINT is always 24 bits, INT is always 32 bits, and BIGINT is always 64 bits.

Nor does the display width constrain any of those types to store less than the full range of values permitted by their data type size.  E.g. TINYINT(1) still allows all values -128 to 127.

---

The number arguments of NUMERIC or DECIMAL have a totally different meaning.  They do determine the precision and scale of the data type, according to standard SQL.