# MySQL Query Needs Optimizations

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this `users` table with:

```
id : int (255)
name: char (100)
last_comment_target: int(100)
last_comment_date: datetime
```

This table has around 1.3mil rows.

`PKEY` and `BTREE` is on `id`, `last_comment_target`, and `last_comment_date`.

And, I am trying to perform a range query:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,5,...[around 5000 ids]) 
AND last_comment_target > 0 
ORDER BY last_comment_dt DESC LIMIT 0,20;
```

Sometimes the query can take as long as 3 seconds. I wonder if there are better ways to optimize this query. Or, if this query can be rewritten.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Where do you get those 5000 ID's from?

Comment: Where are the 5000 ids coming from? If you can put them into a table (or of they're already in a table) and do a join, it may be faster. Even better, if the 5,000 ids can be associated to an attribute in users, you could just specify that as simple condition - and even index it, if necessary.

Comment: this 5000 ids are manually inserted or can they be queried?

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Comment: i'm not an expert on mysql but in sql server its typically faster to do a join than using "IN" statement.  I would try creating a temp table with the 5000s ids then do a join to the table on the ID.

Comment: Not related to the question, but what *int (**255**)* or *int(**100**)* mean? Also *last_comment_date* in table structure and *last_comment_dt* in query. Is PK is composite on *id*, *last_comment_target*, and *last_comment_date*?

Comment: @cularis @doug-kress @AJC @atbebtg the 5000 ids are actually derived from the `friends` table. How do I actually do the `IN` statement?

Is it something like this:

`SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN friends f ON u.id = f.user2 AND f.user2 = [id]` ?

Comment: @petr-abdulin : int(255) means it is a type of integer with size 255. `PK` is applied to `id` only.

Comment: @Heru Setiawan: No, int(255) is only a display width hint.  It does not set the size of the integer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073152/what-does-255-limitation-for-integer-in-mysql-mean/7073251#7073251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM 
    users u
    JOIN (
        SELECT 1 id 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 id
        UNION ALL
        :
        :
        SELECT 5000 id
    ) ids ON ids.id = u.id
WHERE 
    last_comment_target > 0 
ORDER BY 
    last_comment_dt DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if you can help me shed some light on your answer. Why are we using the `SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 id UNION ALL ....` as part of the `JOIN`? Can we actually do a `JOIN` on the table where we derived from the other table? What difference will it make (if any)?

Comment: @Heru This creates a temporary table of all ids. Joining tables usually is a faster solution, but it depends on many factors and you should test it. If you have all ids in some other table then you can use your other table instead of these UNIONS: `select id from other_table`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone that has contributed.

@Karolis seems to point out that an alternative using `join` instead of `range`

So, basically:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...[5000 ids]) AND last_comment_target > 0`

yields in `EXPLAIN` statement a `type` of `RANGE`. The 5000 ids can be generated from another table.

When I switched the above to:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_friends uf ON u.id = uf.to_id
AND u.last_comment_target > 0
AND uf.from_id = [id];
```

It yields in `EXPLAIN` statement two `types`: `ref` and `eq_ref` which is faster than `range` in this query.

The query execution is reduced from 3+ seconds to around 0.2x seconds.

So, lesson learned from my end: *TRY* to use `JOIN` instead of `RANGE` if you have a table that you can derive from.